# How to reduce the storage size of scipy.sparse.dok_matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I wish to build a sparse real matrix using the intermediate [`scipy.sparse.dok_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dok_matrix.html) storage format, then convert the matrix into the [`scipy.sparse.csc_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.html) storage format and perform computations with the resulting matrix. However, the size of the intermediate matrices greatly exceeds my estimates and available memory.

### My environment

```
$ python3 -V
Python 3.4.2
$ pip freeze | grep -E 'scipy|numpy'
numpy==1.14.2
scipy==1.0.1
```

### Using `numpy`

When I build a 20,000 × 20,000 numpy array of 16bit integers as follows, I would estimate the size would be 20000 ** 2 * 16 / 8 / 2 ** 20 ≈ 763M. The process has a Resident Set Size (RSS) of 815M as reported by the `htop` unix tool, which matches my estimate.

```py
import numpy as np

n = 20000
M = np.ones((n, n), dtype=np.uint16)
```

### Using `dict`

When I build a 20,000 × 20,000 `scipy.sparse.dok_matrix` using 16bit integers as keys and values as follows, I would estimate the size would be 20000 ** 2 * (16 * 3) / 8 / 2 ** 30 ≈ 2.24G plus some minor overhead of the hash table. However, the process has a RSS of 66.4G, which shows that I made a grave error in my estimate.

```py
import numpy as np

n = 20000
M = dict()
for i in range(n):
    i = np.uint16(i)
    for j in range(n):
        j = np.uint16(j)
        M[(i, j)] = np.uint16(1)
```

### Using `scipy.sparse.dok_matrix`

When I build a 20,000 × 20,000 `scipy.sparse.dok_matrix` using 16bit integers as keys and values as follows, I would estimate the size would be again 20000 ** 2 * (16 * 3) / 8 / 2 ** 30 ≈ 2.24G plus some minor overhead of the hash table. However, the process has a RSS of 81.3G, which is even farther from my estimate than the `dict` example.

```py
from scipy.sparse import dok_matrix
import numpy as np

n = 20000
M = dok_matrix((n, n), dtype=np.uint16)
for i in range(n):
    i = np.uint16(i)
    for j in range(n):
        j = np.uint16(j)
        M[i, j] = 1
```

Comment: Explain your estimates

Comment: What is unclear?

Comment: Please explicitly state your question. I'd say it could be "_How do I make a `dok_matrix` smaller than a regular non-sparse matrix, or even a dict?_"

Comment: It can't really be smaller than a non-sparse matrix. However, I would prefer if the sparse matrix containing the same data weren't 100 times as large.

Answer (score 2):

While you can control the `dtype` of the `data`, values, of a `dok`, you can't control the key storage.

Looking at the `dok_matrix` class code:

```
def __setitem__(self, index, x):
   ...
   v = np.asarray(x, dtype=self.dtype)
   ...
   dict.__setitem__(self, (int(i), int(j)), v[()])
```

So the elements are stored as numpy 'scalar' objects of chosen `dtype`:

```
In [129]: M = sparse.dok_matrix((10,10), dtype=np.uint16)
In [130]: M[0,0] = 1
In [131]: list(M.items())
Out[131]: [((0, 0), 1)]
In [132]: type(_[0][1])
Out[132]: numpy.uint16
```

I don't know enough about Python dict storage to estimate the memory required for the hash table.  I don't think the actual indexing tuples are stored anywhere, just their hashes.

Another recent question tried to compare the memory use of arrays and lists using `sys.getsizeof`.  Using that on this dok:

```
In [133]: sys.getsizeof(M)     # 1 item
Out[133]: 256
In [134]: for i in range(10):
     ...:     for j in range(10):
     ...:         M[i,j]=1
     ...:         
In [135]: sys.getsizeof(M)     # full
Out[135]: 4720
```

With lists, `getsizeof` only captures the object overhead and pointer buffer.  I don't know what it captures with a dictionary.  Maybe just the hash table.  The data values are stored elsewhere in memory:

```
In [136]: sys.getsizeof(Out[131][0][1])
Out[136]: 26
In [137]: M.nnz
Out[137]: 100
In [138]: 26*M.nnz
Out[138]: 2600
```

Storage of the other sparse formats is easier to estimate. `coo` and `csr` use 3 numpy arrays.  Index arrays are stored as `int32` or `int64` depending on the dimensions of the matrix.

---

To get a rough estimate of memory use, I wrote various formats to files:

```
In [164]: np.save('Mdense',M.A)
In [165]: sparse.save_npz('Mcsr',M.tocsr())
In [166]: sparse.save_npz('Mcoo',M.tocoo())

In [179]: f = open('Mdok',mode='wb')
In [180]: pickle.Pickler(f).dump(M)
In [181]: f.close()

In [182]: ll M*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 paul  900 Apr 16 11:53 Mcoo.npz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 paul  911 Apr 16 11:53 Mcsr.npz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 paul  328 Apr 16 11:53 Mdense.npy
-rw-rw-r-- 1 paul 3023 Apr 16 11:57 Mdok
```

Since the `M` is full, it makes sense that the sparse `coo` format would take up 3x the space of a dense array.  `coo` has a 100  element array for each of `data`, `row` and `col`.  `csr` tries to condense the `row` array, but the difference isn't always that signficant.

I had to use `pickle` for the `dok`.  `sparse.save_npz` doesn't handle `dok`.

Comment: The indexing tuples must be stored to resolve hash collisions.

Comment: http://maciejkula.github.io/2015/02/22/incremental-sparse-matrices/ suggests using dynamic arrays from the [`array.array`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) standard library module to build the COO matrix incrementally. However, `array.array` uses ANSI C data types, whereas there does not seem to be a way to request C `float` in numpy, which can correspond to either `np.float32` or `np.float64` according to the architecture. Therefore, I fear that the `np.frombuffer` call in the article is actually undefined behavior.